# TFS "Assign To" is showing too many users

Tags: tfs

I am connected to a TFS server, and when I create a work item (Bug, Task, etc.), the "Assign To" shows WAY too many users. I cannot find a way to limit the users shown that will affect anyone else who connects to the server.

For example, I have under the "Assign To" dropdown:

```
Administrator
LOCALE SERVICE
User 1
User 2
User 3
User 4
User 5
```

I want the "Assign To" dropdown to only show:

```
User 1
User 3
User 5
```

How would I do this, so that it changes on the server, and if anyone new connects to the server, they can only see the three users on the "Assign To" dropdown?

Comment: This should probably be over at programmers.stackexchange.com. Good question, but not a programming solution type deal--more about tools.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's what you should do:

1. Open the **Visual Studio Command Prompt**. This will give you a command line window with the PATH set to run VS / TFS tools
2. Download the **Work Item Type definition** that you want to modify (e.g. Bug, Task):

   - `witadmin exportwitd /collection:collectionurl /p:project /n:typename [/f:filename]`

   This will give you the WIT's definition, in XML format.
3. Open the XML file. You will edit the **rules** for the **Assigned To** field. Find the term **"System.AssignedTo"**
4. In the **Allowed Values** rule element, modify (or add if none exists) your **List Item** element to limit the values to members of one (or more) **TFS / Active Directory** group(s).
   Your field definition should look like this:

`<FIELD name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">

        <HELPTEXT>The person currently working on this bug</HELPTEXT>

        <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />

        <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">

<!-- Below is a TFS group. Note you actually type "[project]" verbatim -->

          <LISTITEM value="[project]\Contributors" />

<!-- Below is an AD group. The name and group are examples only -->

          <LISTITEM value="MYDOMAIN\Developers" /> 
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>

      </FIELD>`

**Importing your changes:**

1. Save your file.
2. In the command line window type the following:
   `witadmin importwitd /collection:collectionurl /p:project /f:filename`

That's it. Your work item type is now limited to the people you want.

Comment: You can get the file through visual studio and upload the file using visual studio. Might want to update your answer to reflect that you can do some of this in visual studio.

Comment: You need to install the team foundation power tools in order to do that.

Comment: I did not, unless it comes with ultimate

Comment: Someone did... VS 2010 doesn't come with the GUI extension for working with TFS work items. If you're talking about the menu option Tools > Process Editor > Import / Export WIT, that is definitely the TFPT.

Comment: I tried the exact same, but get TF26204 error when importing - I suppose it can not find the project group that I have specified. Also, when I go through the GUI integrated into VS (TFSPowerTools?), I only get the global groups and no project-local groups in the dropdown.

Comment: Ok, I have to read more carefully.. [project] verbatim should be good enough an explanation. So it has to be [project] and not [MyMainProject] or similar - same for all different project names and always refers to current project.

Answer (score 13):

See my answer here for 2012, it may be similar: [Visual Studio - Don't display all domain users in "Assign To" field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578355/visual-studio-dont-display-all-domain-users-in-assign-to-field/15640376#15640376)

> The problem was that **[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Valid Users** included
>   **[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Administrators** which included **[BUILT IN]\Administrators**
>
> In the **TFS Server Administration Console** I selected **Application
>   Tier** and clicked **Group Membership**.  I then double-clicked on
>   **[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Administrators** and removed **[BUILT IN]\Administrators**.
>
> Now I only see my team and not all the SQL admins and engineers that
>   were local admins on the server.  All without any command line or
>   addons.

Comment: Nice Scott. I almost got this solution, before your post, I was trying to figure this out removing [BUILTIN]\Administrators group from [Collection]\Project Collection Administrators group inside collection group membership. Just to warn that I need to stop/start DefaultCollection in order to changes make effect. It's weird, because I have another collect besides DefaultCollection that I didnt need to stop/start to see the changes.

Comment: Worked for me in TFS 2013 as well

Answer (score 4):

You can:

1) go here https://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/releases and download the latest Team Project Manager;

2) launch it (an *.exe file in the archive);

3) connect it to your project;

4) go to "work item configuration" on the right;

5) then to "work item types";

6) select your item type (Product Backlog Item for instance), click "edit";

7) do what Assaf Stone suggested above, in my case it was just replacing

```
<VALIDUSER />
```

with

```
<ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
    <LISTITEM value="[project]\Contributors" />
</ALLOWEDVALUES>
```

8) save your changes;

That's it! BTW, the tool can come in handy for some other customizations as well.

Answer (score 3):

After installing TFS power tools for Visual Studio.

1. From the menu open `Tools` --> `Process Editor` --> `Work Item Types` --> `Open WIT (WorkItem) Type from Server`.
2. Select the Collection and the Project and The Work Item that you need to make changes to.
3. Open the `Assigned To` field and Click on `Rules Tab`
4. Edit the Valid user an add the "group name" which you wanted to display.

Then save the Workitem by selection save in Visual Studio.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate group under the collection and add the users.
Open the Process template Add a rule to assigned to field Assigned to "Valid User" and select the Group which you created.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't even know where the Process template is on the server. Can you give me a link or a step by step instruction on how to do this?

Comment: Worth noting that you would have to do this for *every* work item type on the server.  The default behaviour is to include every valid TFS user.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at a few keywords from hems I got some good google results.

The first thing you need to do is go into visual studio, and select team menu and from there go to collection settings. You will see process template and from there you can download one you have.

After you download it you can then modify any settings you want. When you are done, go to the same menu and this time click upload.

That is all it takes, but note you can only select this new one on project creation.