# TFS 2008 WIT - Limiting System.AssignedTo based on group selection in other field

Tags: tfs, schema, tfs-workitem

I'm attempting to create a field ALLOWEDVALUES rule to limit the assignment of users based on another field.  As an example.

User Groups

[PROJECT]\Developers
[PROJECT]\Project Managers

In the TFS Work Item Tracking Form I have two fields

Assignee Group:
Assignee [System.AssignedTo]:

Based on the value in Assignee Group I want to limit the user list in System.AssignedTo to whatever users are in the selected group.

Ideas?  I cannot seem to find an answer that matches what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

open power tools select project , select work item type , open work flow and then select the state from which u want to restrict the user

```
work item=task
state=propose
assign to=developers

what u have to do for that simply go on the state propose select new> add assign to >add new rule>valid user>select the developers group.
```

now when u create a task and its state is propose then only developers will be shown in assign to field.
vote up answer if it help. feel free to ask any help!

Answer (score 0):

You might find this post helpful [TFS "Assign To" is showing too many users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771030/tfs-assign-to-is-showing-too-many-users)

In your case, make sure to add `for` attribute to apply the rule to specific user group. 
Check the schema reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa337646(v=vs.80).aspx