# Visual Studio - Don't display all domain users in "Assign To" field

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

If I load up TFS Web Access and go to Security > Users, I only see the 3 people I've added to my team.  However, when I try to assign a task to someone in Web Access or in Visual Studio, it lists a bunch of users from the domain (not all users, looks like all IT people).  Where does this come from?  How can I change it... without exporting, editing and importing files via command line?

**update:** I found this line in the MSDN documentation:

> **Team Foundation \Team Foundation Valid Users**
>
> Members of this group
>   have access to Team Foundation Server. This group automatically
>   contains all users and groups that have been added anywhere within
>   Team Foundation Server. You cannot modify the membership of this
>   group.

I really don't understand... this is our own team's server, a separate install from the main dev team.  I have no idea how these other 30 or 40 users got in this group.  Major bonus <3 for any help on this.  MikeR's answer will allow me to set administrators as the only assigness which will technically fix the issue, but I'd rather be able to use the groups as they were intended if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that **[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Valid Users** included **[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Administrators** which included **[BUILT IN]\Administrators**

In the **TFS Server Administration Console** I selected **Application Tier** and clicked **Group Membership**.  I then double-clicked on **[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Administrators** and removed **[BUILT IN]\Administrators**.

Now I only see my team and not all the SQL admins and engineers that were local admins on the server.  All without any command line or addons.

Comment: Thanks for this...I was able to remove the built-in Administrators group from TFS Administrators. However, even after TFS has re-synced with AD, the extra domain admin accounts are still appearing in the Assigned To dropdowns. Do we need to wait for the server to clean them up or something? (I suppose I could also change the WIT as in MikeR's answer below...)

Comment: It's been a long time... You might have to restart TFS services, but I don't think so.  Are there any other unexpected groups in `Team Foundation Administrators` or `Valid Users`?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice the notification from your reply. The extra accounts are still appearing, but I haven't been able to look at it since, nor have I had time to schedule a restart. I'll bookmark this though, and I'll report back next time I am able to look at it. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't help in my situation, even after restarting the TFS services

Answer (score 1):

This list of possible assings is defined in the WorkItemTypeDefinition. Usually you would export and import this. If you have the TFS PowerTools (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) installed, you can directly work with the WITD in Visual Studio.

To do this, open "Tools->Process Editor->Work Item Types->Open WIT from Server". Choose the TeamProjectCollection you want to connect to and than choose the TeamProject and WorkItemType you are having trouble with.

Check the rules for "AssignedTo" field. Default could be the "ValidUser" rule, which includes every permitted user in TFS. Remove that rule and add a new one "AllowedValues" rule with values like "[project]\Project Administrators", than only "Project Administrators" can be assigned to this Work Item.

If there is already a group defined and not all "ValidUser", remove users from the group set is set there.

Comment: Very helpful, but any idea how to define "ValidUsers"?  I don't understand why it's such a large group or where it came from.

Comment: I went ahead and set it to Administrators and saved the WIT file, but the other names still showed up.  Will this require a restart of a service or something?

Comment: The ValidUsers should be the group "Project Collection Valid Users", so every user that is permitted in the collection somehow. After changing the rules you need to refresh your TeamExplorer and than all open WorkItems to see the changes.