# assign work item to user from trusted domain

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have AzureDevops 2019 on premise with users in domain 1 and users in domains 2. There is full trust between the domains. It is possible to add users from both domains to tfs security groups, however it is possible to assign work items, only to few specific users of domain 2. Can u please advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We seem to have resolved the problem. It seems that TFS needs two things so that users in domain 2 will be recognized for assign to : (1) place the user in a group that is member of the basic service groups, (2) time to synch with active directory.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

> however it is possible to assign work items, only to few specific
>   users of domain 2

For this issue , do you refer to show only the specified users in the "Assign To" dropdown?
If so, here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771030/tfs-assign-to-is-showing-too-many-users) you can refer to to achieve it:

1.Open the `Visual Studio Command Prompt`. This will give you a command
        line window with the PATH set to run VS / TFS tools

2.Download the `Work Item Type definition` that you want to modify (e.g.
    Bug, Task):

```
witadmin exportwitd /collection:collectionurl /p:project /n:typename [/f:filename]
```

This will give you the WIT's definition, in XML format.

3.Open the XML file. You will edit the rules for the `Assigned To`
    field. Find the term "`System.AssignedTo`"

4.In the `Allowed Values` rule element, modify your List Item element to limit the values to members of one (or
    more) TFS / Active Directory group(s).

After doing these,  you can import the changes in the command line window via : `witadmin importwitd /collection:collectionurl /p:project /f:filename`

You can also refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=azure-devops-2019) for details.

Comment: We do not need to limit the assign to list. On the contrary, we need it to show also users from the other domain. 

Example : user1 in domain 1, user2 and user3 in domain 2. Assign to in domain 1 finds user1 and user2 but doesn't find user3. Can u please advise ?